# Adding sliding UIImageView on customcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I want to change the image in UIImageview when I swip the UIImageview ,I am adding UIScroll view on customcell,on that scrollview I am adding UIImageview And I also want to add UIPagecontrol ,when I swipe on imageview image is changing but dot in the page controller is not changing ,Please anyone help I am new to ios,How can I add sliding imageview with paging on customcell? and how to make paging dots to work,
here is my code

```
                 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
               static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
              customCellForText *cell = [tableObj deq          ueueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
           if (cell==nil) {
               NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle    mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"customCellForText" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];


              scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130, 80, 150, 100)];
               scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
             scrollView.delegate = self;
             [scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
             [scrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
             [cell.contentView addSubview:scrollView];

             for (int i = 0; i < imageArray.count; i++) {
               CGRect frame;
              frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
               frame.origin.y = 0;
              frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

            subview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
             subview.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:i];
              [self.scrollView addSubview:subview];
              }

             self.scrollView.contentSize =   CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * imageArray.count,     self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
             pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(210, 180, 30, 20)];
           pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
           pageControl.numberOfPages = imageArray.count;
           [pageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changePage:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:pageControl];

          UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer    alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTap)];
          tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
           [subview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
           [subview addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
            }

          [cell.commentBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(commentBtnClicked:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
           cell.commentBtn.tag = indexPath.row;
           cell.nameLabel.text=@"amol";




          return cell;
           }

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {
            // Update the page when more than 50% of the previous/next page is visible
             CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
            int page = floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
            self.pageControl.currentPage = page;
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to set the currentPage property of the pageControl when you swipe.

[UIPageControl currentPage](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPageControl/currentPage)

Also you might wanna use this formula for calculating the new page like below

```
NSInteger newPage = (NSUInteger)floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x * 2.0f + pageWidth) / (pageWidth * 2.0f));
```

Comment: self.pageControl.currentPage = page; I have added in scrollViewDidScroll:

Comment: @AmolNikam Can you put a break point in scrollViewDidScroll and test if it is getting called?

Comment: ya scrollViewDidScroll is getting called but it always giving page=0 don't no why??

Comment: Is your scrollViewDidScroll inside cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: No ,it is outside of cellforRowAtIndexPath , in question by mistake it is posted inside